# php array_filter for "False" value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `array_filter` in php:

```
$new_array = array_filter($updated, "check_if_value_is_null_or_false");

function check_if_value_is_null_or_false($val) {
    return !is_null($val);       
};
```

I understand that I can use `is_null` to filter out anything that has `null` value.

I also want to add a condition for string `"False"` as the value.

How would I modify the above?

Comment: Do you mean the string `"False"` or the `false` value as a Boolean?

Comment: Opps. Should have clarified it. I meant for string.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show your research / attempts.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your function name compared to what it's doing. You are stating `check_if_value_is_null_or_false` as you would return `true` if the value is `null` or `"False"`. Although inside you are returning "not null", would you want to return the `true` value or `false` for the second one?

Comment: I don't think my explanation was clear. But I got it working now. Thanks guys.

Comment: @steveKim To improve your question please add your research and attempt(s) into your question and show where you got stuck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you could make your own callback

```
function is_not_null_or_false($value) {
  return !(is_null($value) || $value === false);
}

array_filter($updated, 'is_not_null_or_false');
```

Or you could skip the separate function and do

```
array_filter($updated, function($x) { return !(is_null($x) || $x === false); });
```

---

**EDIT**

it appears you're looking for the *string* `"False"` not the *boolean* value

```
array_filter($updated, function($x) { return !(is_null($x) || $x === "False"); });
```

---

**EDIT 2**

For readability's sake, we changed

```
!is_null($x) && $x !== "False"
```

To

```
!(is_null($x) || $x === "False")
```

According to [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) these are equivalent but the second probably reads better especially given the function's name.

Comment: You could also do `!(is_null($value) || $value === false)`, it might make more sense given the function name.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks, you're probably right. I updated the answer and provided reasoning.

Answer (score -2):

Please check this example:

```
function check_if_value_is_null_or_false($val) {
    return !empty($val);
};
```

more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php
empty() return TRUE when variable is null and false.

Comment: `0`, `"0"`, `""`, `false`, and `[]` would also be filtered out. This does not meet the OP's specs.